# WPF Command - Memory Leak

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, tabcontrol, wpf-4.0

I'm using WPF 4 with the MVVM pattern. I have a TabControl - it looks like:

```
 <TabControl x:Name="Items" ItemsSource="{Binding Screens}" 
                            SelectedItem="{Binding ActiveScreen}">
   <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
       <ContentControl>
            <Button Command="{Binding 
                              DataContext.ScreenCloseCommand, 
                              ElementName=MainWindow}" 
                    CommandParameter="{Binding}">X</Button>
       </ContentControl>
     </DataTemplate>
   </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
```

The problem is, that CommandParameter="{Binding}" holds a strong reference to the currently displayed View/ViewModel. How can i remove that command? In other words: i need a way to remove the Button Command from ItemTemplate by only having a reference of the TabControl.ContentTemplate (ViewModel and View). Something like go through items, find the item, remove command ...

Thanks
Michael

Comment: How you found that command causes memory leak?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you're looking at the wrong problem. It's not the `Binding` that keeps the ViewModel alive. It's the whole `TabControl` and the collection it binds to.

If you described what actual problem are you trying to solve, and not the solution you're unsuccessfully trying to use, we might help you better.

Comment: If i remove the CommandParameter it works - ViewModel / View is collected. What i trying to achive: Closeable tabs with MVVM. MainWindow is my Shell which has the method "ScreenCloseCommand". This method asks the screen (which is passed via CommandParameter) if it can be closed ("CanClose"). Then i remove it from the TabControl bound ObservableList - so it disappears ... But because of the binding cycle a reference is still alive from the Button bound Command -> leak (imo) :-(

Comment: You're right. Under the circumstances you described, the leak does occur. I have no idea how to get rid of it, though.